# "the sizes of the disks" or "the size of the disks"?

Tags: grammar

Consider the following hypothetical example:

There are 3 disk; named X, Y, Z; and each have radius rx, ry, and, rz.

If I want to refer to the set {rx, ry, rz}, would I say

> ... the sizes of the disks

or

> ... the size of the disks

or

> ... the sizes of the disk

Comment: You use singular "disk" twice in your post, but I think that you mean plural "disks". Perhaps you mean singular, but I can't imagine why.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan see the ending of the "disk(s)" too

Comment: OK, so perhaps you meant to ask about "disk" vs. "disks", and I guess that the other one ("there are three disk") is just a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>... the sized of the disks</s> – sized is not a noun.

... the size of the disks – all the disks are the same size “The size of the disks is 20cm.”

... the sizes of the disk - (i) all the disks are different sizes “The sizes of the disks are 20 cm. 30 cm and 35 cm respectively.” (ii) some of the disks are different sizes: "The sizes of the disks are either 29cm or 58cm."

In broad terms, when considering singular or plural, you can omit "of the disks" as this is merely an adjectival.

Comment: what about there was one disk but it would acquire different sizes over time; would I then need to say the sizes of the disk?

Comment: @Our I would say that the disk only has one size but that the size changes. This means that the size is singular. It is analagous to the concept of a child's shoe size changing over time, the child has one shoe size but that size is not fixed.